# Moles/Liters doesn't get simplified to Molar even though Molar*Liters gets simplified to Moles

Tags: simplifying-expressions, units, chemistry

Why can't Mathematica 9 simplify mol/L to M, when it can simplify M*L to mol?

```
 Quantity["Moles" / "Liters"] // UnitSimplify
 (* => 1 mol/L *)

 Quantity["Molar" * "Liters"] // UnitSimplify
 (* => 1 mol *)
```

And is there a way to fix this behaviour?

Comment: Perhaps this is because molar is not in the base SI system and mole is?

Comment: @Sjoerd: I'm not sure if the base vs non-base unit is the issue here. The example in [the documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/UnitSimplify.html) is `UnitSimplify[Quantity[1, ("Joules"/"Seconds")]]` which yields the non-base SI `Quantity[1, "Watts"]`.

Answer (score 4):

I can't comment on whether this functionality is by design or by omission; however, to *fix* this behavior, one can use `UnitConvert`

```
Quantity["Moles" / "Liters"] // UnitSimplify
UnitConvert[%,"Molar"]

(* 1 mol/L *)
(* 1 M *)
```

Comment: Also, there's no problem doing calculations like `Quantity[3, "Moles"/"Liters"] - Quantity[1, "Molar"]`